# How are environment variables used in Jenkins with Windows Batch Command?

Tags: windows, batch-file, hudson, jenkins

I'm trying to use **Jenkins (Global) environment variables** in my xcopy script.

```
${WORKSPACE} doesn't work
"${WORKSPACE}" doesn't work
'${WORKSPACE}' doesn't work
```

Answer (score 148, accepted):

I know nothing about Jenkins, but it looks like you are trying to access environment variables using some form of unix syntax - that won't work.

If the name of the variable is WORKSPACE, then the value is expanded in Windows batch using
`%WORKSPACE%`. That form of expansion is performed at parse time. For example, this will print to screen the value of WORKSPACE

```
echo %WORKSPACE%
```

If you need the value at execution time, then you need to use delayed expansion `!WORKSPACE!`. Delayed expansion is not normally enabled by default. Use `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` to enable it. Delayed expansion is often needed because blocks of code within parentheses and/or multiple commands concatenated by `&`, `&&`, or `||` are parsed all at once, so a value assigned within the block cannot be read later within the same block unless you use delayed expansion.

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set WORKSPACE=BEFORE
(
  set WORKSPACE=AFTER
  echo Normal Expansion = %WORKSPACE%
  echo Delayed Expansion = !WORKSPACE!
)
```

The output of the above is

```
Normal Expansion = BEFORE
Delayed Expansion = AFTER
```

Use `HELP SET` or `SET /?` from the command line to get more information about Windows environment variables and the various expansion options. For example, it explains how to do search/replace and substring operations.

Comment: I totally forgot about that little nit picky detail about windows. Thanks !

Comment: @UtsavGupta
I was also stuck on this. I was using $BUILD_ID earlier. Now happy with %BUILD_ID% on windows.

Answer (score 30):

In windows you should use `%WORKSPACE%`.

Comment: Yes. And in Hudson's "Build/Command/Execute Windows batch command" field.

Comment: %VARIABLE% syntax can also be used to refer User-defined Jenkins variables.

Answer (score 4):

I should this On Windows, environment variable expansion is %BUILD_NUMBER%