# Jenkins cannot run npm or pm2 by itself

Tags: node.js, linux, jenkins, amazon-ec2, npm

So I have a Jenkins CI setup on an EC2 server. I have nodejs and npm installed. Weirdly, Jenkins can access them via the command line if I do something like:

```
sudo -u jenkins node -v
```

However, Jenkins cannot access them inside an actual build runtime, and I get the following errors:

```
npm: command not found
pm2: command not found
```

npm is *definitely* installed, and ec2-user/root users can access it. What PATH do I have to change so that Jenkins can access it too?

Comment: try running `id; env|sort` in a shell build step and see that your environment matches. You probably need to set the environment. You can use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544535/jenkins-global-variables

Comment: Also `sudo` does not load the users (jenkins in your case) environment you need `sudo su -`

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you use the nodejs plugin it will be easier to manage your node and npm in this box. Also, this plugin allows installing some global modules that possibly you will need to build your project:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeJS+Plugin