# How to use Jenkins pipeline variable into powershell or cmd code?

Tags: windows, jenkins, groovy, environment-variables

I am in need of modifying a Jenkins Pipeline script. This is a snippet. It works down to the Def in the rename. The error I get is

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: newFileName for class: groovy.lang.Binding

I am looking to inject the version number into the filename which is then processed by a homegrown app to move it where it needs to go and some other stuff. I have tried passing the concatenated ${version} into the Upload executable but it then errors as a literal instead of a variable.

Update: I predefine the variable and get a new error

> powershell.exe : newFileName : The term 'newFileName' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
> At C:\workspace\workspace\Centurion Dashboard@tmp\durable-eb5db1ae\powershellWrapper.ps1:3 char:1
> & powershell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Comm
>
> - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (newFileName : T...e, or >operable :String) [], RemoteException
>
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Thoughts?

```
stage('Rename') {
      powershell """
        rename-item -Path "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\Advanced Installer\\Projects\\Proj\\Setup Files\\SetupCenturionDashboard.exe" -NewName "OtherProject-${version}.exe"
        def newFileName = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\Advanced Installer\\Projects\\Proj\\Setup Files\\OtherProject-" + ${version} + ".exe"
        echo ${newFileName} 
    """
} 

    stage('Upload') {
      bat label: 'Upload', script: 'C:\\Static\\BuildHelper\\BuildHelper.exe ${newFileName} "develop" "home" "${version}"'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### powershell != groovy

You cannot run groovy inside of powershell block

```
powershell """

"""
```

and `def newFileName` is groovy, that is why you get the error:

```
The term 'newFileName' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet...
```

As you can see, **newFileName** executable does not exist on windows.

### variables on windows

If you just need to pass the version and newFileName variables to your powershell or bat code, you need to use the [windows syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8607291/3957754) `%var%` for variables, not the unix `${var}` and use global variables if it is possible in your pipeline:

```
def version = "1.0.0";
def newFileName;

stage('Rename') {
    powershell """
        rename-item -Path "C:\\Users\\foo.exe" -NewName "OtherProject-%version%.exe"
    """
    newFileName = "C:\\Users\\OtherProject-${version}.exe"
} 

stage('Upload') {
    bat label: 'Upload', script: 'C:\\Static\\BuildHelper\\BuildHelper.exe %newFileName% "develop" "home" "%version%"'
}
```